# Views in Fragment Return NullPointerException After Selecting Navigation Item

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in an activity that will update a fragment in the activity. All works fine, but when I rotate the device and press one of the navigation drawer items, it crashes because views in the fragment are null.

Here where I implement navigation items selection. I pass data to an interface method that the fragment implements.

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    // Call interface method that GalleriesFragment implements
    UpdateGalleries updateGalleries =  (UpdateGalleries) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    updateGalleries.fetchGalleriesOf(mSelectedCategory, categoryId);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return false;
}
```

Here is the portion of the fragment where I implement the interface method:

```
    @Override
public void fetchGalleriesOf(String category, String categoryId) {

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // progressBar is null

    // Listen for firebase values
    listenToGalleries();

    // Attach listener to reference
    if(category.equals("Home")){
        category = "Recently added";
        References.galleriesRef.orderByChild(Constants.TIMESTAMP).addValueEventListener(mGalleriesListener);
    }else {
        References.galleriesRef.orderByChild(Constants.CATEGORY_ID).equalTo(categoryId)
                .addValueEventListener(mGalleriesListener);
    }

    mCategoryTV.setText(category);

}// End fetchGalleriesOf
```

Here is the fragment in activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.thunderbolt.thebolt.ui.fragment.GalleriesFragment"
tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity"/>
```

The mProgressBar and mCategoryTV in the fragment return null pointer exception despite initializing them in onCreateView of the fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

    // Reset list
    mGalleries = new ArrayList<>();
    mGalleriesAdapter = new GalleriesAdapter(mGalleries, this);

    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_galleries);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mGalleriesAdapter);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mCategoryTV = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
    mCategoryTV.setText(mCategory);

    mProgressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mNoDataTV = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_data);

    return rootView;
}
```

EDIT:
crash logs:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.thunderbolt.thebolt, PID: 31441
>                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                at com.thunderbolt.thebolt.ui.fragment.GalleriesFragment.fetchGalleriesOf(GalleriesFragment.java:146)
>                                                                                at com.thunderbolt.thebolt.ui.activity.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:191)
>                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:154)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:89)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
>                                                                                at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232)
>                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)

Comment: Add crash logs.

Comment: see the edit i added the Logcat

Comment: Where are you initializing `progressBar` ? I don't see it in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: it's on the bottom of onCreateView()

Comment: No it's not. The one at the bottom is `mProgressBar` and not `progressBar`

Comment: ok sorry, I did some renaming and got mixed up. I'll edit the question but It's the same in the code.

Comment: solved it. It was because the fragment didn't have an id attribute on portrait xml file but had one on landscape xml

Answer (score 0):

In the `Fragment` try to add this to save its data:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save the fragment's state
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

In your Activity, don't re-add the fragment, otherwise they would be overlapped. I.e from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime) :

```
// However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
// then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
// we could end up with overlapping fragments.
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that prevented the crash but it disabled the fragment from updating when navigation drawer item clicked

Comment: Maybe you didn't use the `Bundle savedInstanceState` in your Fragment or in your Activity and you reset some data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved the problem. It was because fragment in xml didn't have an id attribute in portrait, but it had one in landscape xml.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

**Android Basic Device Rotation Flow**

In normal case when you rotate the device so your activity will be destroyed and re-create.

so first check the size of the fragment list before getting a fragment.

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 0) {
    UpdateGalleries updateGalleries =  (UpdateGalleries) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    updateGalleries.fetchGalleriesOf(mSelectedCategory, categoryId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the fragment declaration in the xml didn't have an id attribute for the portrait mode, but had an id for landscape mode. Now I supplied an id for both:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_galleries"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.thunderbolt.thebolt.ui.fragment.GalleriesFragment"
tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity"/>
```